# Cannot get logging to work right with embedded Jetty

Tags: java, eclipse, slf4j, logback, embedded-jetty

I have an app using embedded Jetty. Everything works well, except for logging. I am now trying to  use logback, but am getting fatal errors.

The app loads as you can see:

```
 $ java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:PermSize=64M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Xms1G -Xmx1G -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp -jar /usr/local/mexp/mexp.jar server /usr/local/mexp/mexp.json
10:46:02.093 [main] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging to Logger[org.eclipse.jetty.util.log] via org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
10:46:02.098 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @76ms
```

followed by pages and pages of DEBUG statements describing loading of every class in my app. This suggests it is not finding the logback.xml, where I have set logging level for org.eclipse.jetty to ERROR.

Eventually, I am getting the following exceptions when the app loads:

```
10:46:30.349 [main] DEBUG o.e.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader - loaded class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@659c2931
10:46:30.354 [main] WARN  o.e.j.u.component.AbstractLifeCycle - FAILED o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@4e4e745{/,file:/usr/local/mexp/resources/webapp/,STARTING}{file:/usr/local/mexp/mexp.jar}: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppClassLoader) of the current class, org/slf4j/LoggerFactory, and the class loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for resolved class, org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder, have different Class objects for the type LoggerFactory; used in the signature
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppClassLoader) of the current class, org/slf4j/LoggerFactory, and the class loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for resolved class, org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder, have different Class objects for the type LoggerFactory; used in the signature
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:306) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:276) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:288) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at com.rc.util.logging.RCLog.<init>(RCLog.java:28) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at com.rc.commonwebapp.servlet.filter.SessionTXManager.<init>(SessionTXManager.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context.createInstance(ContextHandler.java:2370) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.createFilter(ServletContextHandler.java:1146) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:120) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:850) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:298) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1341) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1334) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [mexp.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132) [mexp.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:380) [mexp.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114) [mexp.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61) [mexp.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:347) [mexp.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [mexp.jar:na]
    at com.pronto.JettyWebApp.main(JettyWebApp.java:95) [mexp.jar:na]
```

and

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppClassLoader) of the current class, org/slf4j/LoggerFactory, and the class loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for resolved class, org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder, have different Class objects for the type LoggerFactory; used in the signature
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:306) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:276) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:288) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at com.rc.util.logging.RCLog.<init>(RCLog.java:28) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at com.rc.commonwebapp.servlet.filter.SessionTXManager.<init>(SessionTXManager.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context.createInstance(ContextHandler.java:2370) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.createFilter(ServletContextHandler.java:1146) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:120) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:850) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:298) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1341) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1334) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:380) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:347) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[mexp.jar:na]
    at com.pronto.JettyWebApp.main(JettyWebApp.java:95) [mexp.jar:na]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppClassLoader) of the current class, org/slf4j/LoggerFactory, and the class loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for resolved class, org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder, have different Class objects for the type LoggerFactory; used in the signature
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:306)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:276)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:288)
    at com.rc.util.logging.RCLog.<init>(RCLog.java:28)
    at com.rc.commonwebapp.servlet.filter.SessionTXManager.<init>(SessionTXManager.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context.createInstance(ContextHandler.java:2370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.createFilter(ServletContextHandler.java:1146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:850)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1341)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1334)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.pronto.JettyWebApp.main(JettyWebApp.java:95)
```

Some web searching on java.lang.LinkageError suggests that Jetty and my app have different class loaders that are conflicting when trying to load LoggerFactory. I'm not sure what to do next.

ETA: 
Per @PavelHoral's suggestion I added `<scope>provided</scope>` to my pom.xml (dependencyManagement section) but that results in this when I attempt to start the app:

```
2014-09-28 16:47:42.491:INFO::main: Logging initialized @66ms
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at com.rc.util.config.ConfigurationManager.<clinit>(ConfigurationManager.java:31)
    at com.pronto.JettyWebApp.main(JettyWebApp.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 2 more
```

ETA: Per suggestion by @hd1 I added the bridge, which got rid of the LinkageError, so we're part way there. I'm still stymied by the fact that all of the logging goes to stdout and it's still at level DEBUG - not acceptable for a prod environment for sure, so I need to be able to configure this. Here is my logback.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>/usr/local/mexp/logs/mexp.service.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>"%-5p [%d{dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss}] [%t] %-20c %-3x:%m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="AXIS" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>/usr/local/mexp/logs/axis.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-5p [%d{dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss}] :%m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="AXIS"/>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.apache">
        <level value="ERROR"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.quartz">
        <level value="ERROR" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.hibernate">
        <level value="ERROR" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.apache.struts.action">
        <level value="INFO"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.apache.catalina.cluster">
        <level value="INFO"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org">
        <level value="ERROR" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="net">
        <level value="ERROR" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender" additivity="false">
        <level value="ERROR"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.mchange">
        <level value="ERROR"/>
    </logger>

    <!-- this silences the HttpClient chatter that starts with "httpclient.wire.header" and "httpclient.wire.content" -->
    <logger name="org.apache.commons.httpclient">
        <level value="fatal"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="httpclient.wire.header">
        <level value="fatal"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="httpclient.wire.content">
        <level value="fatal"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.eclipse.jetty">
        <level value="ERROR"/>
    </logger>

    <!-- Log the real SQL -->
    <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL">
        <level value="ERROR"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

ETA: I also tried the logging separation described [here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/loggingSeparation.html) - added this to web.xml:

```
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>logback/context-name</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>mexp</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

and this in my jetty runner main method

```
System.setProperty("logback.ContextSelector", "JNDI");
```

(and changed the name of the logback file to logback-mexp.xml) but all of that results in no change in behavior.

We're definitely getting closer, but for the bounty I need the whole solution. Thanks!

---

ETA the current state of things. I no longer get the LinkageError. My app loads and performs fine. In fact there has been a considerable improvement in that now I don't get pages and pages of DEBUG lines in stdout. I still get all my logging in stdout, like so:

```
 $ java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:PermSize=64M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Xms1G -Xmx1G -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp -jar /usr/local/mexp/mexp.jar server /usr/local/mexp/mexp.json
Oct 01, 2014 3:54:28 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Oct 01, 2014 3:54:28 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Oct 01 15:54:28 EDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Oct 01, 2014 3:54:28 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [mexpPapiContext.xml]
Oct 01, 2014 3:54:28 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 352 ms
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/mexp/resources/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/mexp/mexp.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
15:54:28,596  INFO GlobalRootManager:85 - Entering initialization
15:54:28,840  INFO GlobalRootManager:85 - Exiting initialization
15:54:28,868  INFO FileUtil:220 -  -> Found /mpds.properties in resource bundle
Oct 01, 2014 3:54:29 PM org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet initChain
INFO: Loading chain catalog from jar:file:/usr/local/mexp/resources/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/struts-core-1.3.10.jar!/org/apache/struts/chain/chain-config.xml
Oct 01, 2014 3:54:29 PM org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet initChain
INFO: Loading chain catalog from jar:file:/usr/local/mexp/mexp.jar!/org/apache/struts/chain/chain-config.xml
Oct 01, 2014 3:54:29 PM org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources
INFO: Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/struts/validator-rules.xml'
Oct 01, 2014 3:54:29 PM org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources
INFO: Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/struts/validation-mexp.xml'
15:54:29,529  INFO QuartzStartupServlet:85 - Entering servlet init.
15:54:29,562  INFO StdSchedulerFactory:1184 - Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
15:54:29,575  INFO SchedulerSignalerImpl:61 - Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
15:54:29,575  INFO QuartzScheduler:240 - Quartz Scheduler v.2.2.1 created.
15:54:29,576  INFO XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin:200 - Registering Quartz Job Initialization Plug-in.
15:54:29,578  INFO RAMJobStore:155 - RAMJobStore initialized.
15:54:29,578  INFO QuartzScheduler:305 - Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.2.1) 'MexpScheduler' with instanceId 'dev'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 5 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

15:54:29,578  INFO StdSchedulerFactory:1339 - Quartz scheduler 'MexpScheduler' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
15:54:29,578  INFO StdSchedulerFactory:1343 - Quartz scheduler version: 2.2.1
15:54:29,592  INFO XMLSchedulingDataProcessor:471 - Parsing XML file: mexp-dev-jobs.xml with systemId: mexp-dev-jobs.xml
15:54:29,948  INFO XMLSchedulingDataProcessor:996 - Adding 13 jobs, 13 triggers.
15:54:29,949  INFO XMLSchedulingDataProcessor:1034 - Adding job: skuLevelBiddingReportGroup.skuLevelBiddingReportJob
15:54:29,951  INFO XMLSchedulingDataProcessor:1034 - Adding job: emailNotificationsGroup.emailNotificationsJob
15:54:29,952  INFO XMLSchedulingDataProcessor:1034 - Adding job: balanceReplenishmentGroup.balanceReplenishmentJob
15:54:29,953  INFO XMLSchedulingDataProcessor:1034 - Adding job: balanceReplenishmentCappedInvoiceGroup.balanceReplenishmentCappedInvoiceJob
15:54:29,954  INFO XMLSchedulingDataProcessor:1034 - Adding job: merchantTxnProcessingGroup.merchantTxnProcessingJob
15:54:29,956  INFO XMLSchedulingDataProcessor:1034 - Adding job: feedFileManagerGroup.feedFileManagerJob
15:54:29,957  INFO XMLSchedulingDataProcessor:1034 - Adding job: merchantPaymentManagerGroup.merchantPaymentManagerJob
15:54:29,958  INFO XMLSchedulingDataProcessor:1032 - Replacing job: merchantTxnProcessingGroup.merchantTxnProcessingJob
15:54:29,958  INFO XMLSchedulingDataProcessor:1034 - Adding job: expiredAccountUpdaterGroup.expiredAccountUpdaterJob
15:54:29,959  INFO XMLSchedulingDataProcessor:1034 - Adding job: placementsForDatasyncUpdaterGroup.placementsForDatasyncUpdaterJob
15:54:29,960  INFO XMLSchedulingDataProcessor:1034 - Adding job: placementPaymentProcessingGroup.placementPaymentProcessingJob
15:54:29,961  INFO XMLSchedulingDataProcessor:1034 - Adding job: switchingMerchantsToInvoiceGroup.switchingMerchantsToInvoiceJob
15:54:29,962  INFO XMLSchedulingDataProcessor:1034 - Adding job: toggleActiveStateGroup.toggleActiveStateJob
15:54:29,963  INFO QuartzScheduler:575 - Scheduler MexpScheduler_$_dev started.
15:54:29,982  INFO LoggingTriggerHistoryPlugin:387 - Trigger JobSchedulingDataLoaderPlugin.JobSchedulingDataLoaderPlugin_jobInitializer_mexp-dev-jobs_xml fired job JobSchedulingDataLoaderPlugin.JobSchedulingDataLoaderPlugin_jobInitializer_mexp-dev-jobs_xml at:  15:54:29 10/01/2014
15:54:29,983  INFO LoggingJobHistoryPlugin:469 - Job JobSchedulingDataLoaderPlugin.JobSchedulingDataLoaderPlugin_jobInitializer_mexp-dev-jobs_xml fired (by trigger JobSchedulingDataLoaderPlugin.JobSchedulingDataLoaderPlugin_jobInitializer_mexp-dev-jobs_xml) at:  15:54:29 10/01/2014
15:54:29,984  INFO LoggingJobHistoryPlugin:513 - Job JobSchedulingDataLoaderPlugin.JobSchedulingDataLoaderPlugin_jobInitializer_mexp-dev-jobs_xml execution complete at  15:54:29 10/01/2014 and reports: null
15:54:29,984  INFO LoggingTriggerHistoryPlugin:433 - Trigger JobSchedulingDataLoaderPlugin.JobSchedulingDataLoaderPlugin_jobInitializer_mexp-dev-jobs_xml completed firing job JobSchedulingDataLoaderPlugin.JobSchedulingDataLoaderPlugin_jobInitializer_mexp-dev-jobs_xml at  15:54:29 10/01/2014 with resulting trigger instruction code: DO NOTHING
```

Comment: Are you using Maven? If so, show us your dependencies please. Or better, show your application structure. The error suggests that you are packaging slf4j with your webapp, but also reference it from META-INF of your executable JAR. I am not a Jetty expert, but one of this should not have slf4j on their classpath (probably the webapp).

Comment: i am using maven. this is a huge application, with 11 modules and almost N-1 dependencies. i'm happy to share pom.xml but i don't want to paste the whole thing in here. the webapp and several other modules use slf4j extensively, so i'm not sure how i could omit it as a dependency and get the app to compile. i already have an exclusion of slf4j in all modules that use it, but it's still getting included. is there a way to compile without subsequently including the dependency in the war (which is included inside the uber-jar)?

Comment: It looks like `slf4j` find more than one instance of `LoggerFactory`. I can see that jetty logs using `org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog`. I'm not used to jetty (using tomcat ...) but how does jetty logging works ? What happens if you try to log through slf4j without adding logback to the classpath ? Does slf4j try to use jetty logging ?

Comment: @kewpiedoll99 You can easily exclude dependencies from the WAR file by setting them as `<scope>provided</scope>`. You can set this globally if you do this in some common parent POM within `<dependencyManagement>` section.

Answer (score 4):

Please see [this page on the slf4j site](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html). I suspect you've not included the appropriate bridge jar. For example, for [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j), you're going to need the following stanzas in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope that helps. If not, feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't help. Still getting the same `java.lang.LinkageError` when I replace log4j with log4j-over-slf4j.

Comment: You don't replace it, you add the bridge jar to your pom. I've given an example of what you need.

Comment: Thanks. I restored the log4j include and added the other two dependencies; the app starts up and there's no LinkageError, which is great! However, the logging is still in DEBUG level and all going to the stdout. Any idea what I need to do next to get the logging to use my configs? I have a logback.xml in my classpath, which I'll add to my original post, above.

Comment: I just tried starting the app (which I start from the command line) with `> temp.log` and *most* of the output goes to that log file, but a little remains. In this I find complaints about having "both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError" and this: "SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]" - thoughts?

Comment: ... and if I comment out all inclusions of slf4j-log4j12 then the LinkageError returns and my app fails.

Comment: It's critical that you follow instructions *to the letter* with computers. Try removing log4j-over-slf4j.jar from your pom.xml file, what happens then?

Comment: "with computers"? don't be condescending, it makes you look like a douche. and you've been so helpful so far. so if i do that, my app starts up without the LinkageError. the logs are still being sent to stdout. it looks like log4j-over-slf4j is unnecessary, but that slf4j-log4j12 fixes the LinkageError.

Comment: Configuration is done using the *underlying logging system*. Therefore, using a [FileAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/FileAppender.html) for log4j will be helpful. If this doesn't work, please add your log4j.properties file to the question.

Comment: i don't have a log4j.properties file; i have a logback.xml, which i already added to the question. are you saying that i have no control over what logging system is used? i have so many dependencies that conflicts among them in what logging package they use is essentially unavoidable. spring uses commons-logging. jetty seems to use slf4j but i can't tell what type. also, which of those IS the underlying logging system?

Comment: Does anything appear in the log files you've specified in logback.xml?

Comment: nothing. i'm going to update my question with the current state of affairs.

Comment: do you think the fact that my war file seems to contain two copies of logback.xml could be an issue? `jar -tvf mexp.jar | grep logback.xml` shows two listings, `5243 Wed Oct 01 16:21:12 EDT 2014 logback.xml` and `5243 Wed Oct 01 16:21:12 EDT 2014 WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml`

Comment: The only one that is accessed is the one at the root, I don't think the other causes any harm. However, if you want to remove it from your maven build, I suspect the one you want is in `src/main/resources` and not in any other place.

Comment: I appreciate your trying to find a solution with me. Ultimately, though, the best I could get was to redirect the output to a file, so I'm not awarding you the bounty; I gave you a +1 so you should get the auto-award of half the bounty in about an hour.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry, I didn't solve your problem completely.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a silver bullet here: logging in Java takes many forms and it takes attention to detail to get it right. Especially when class-loaders come in to play as is the case with web-apps.

The explanation about how logging works with Slf4j by Joakim Erdfelt is pretty good (I saw this in the [mail-conversation](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg05192.html) you had with him earlier).

I can only add to do a proper clean-up:

- put the jar-files for Logback, the Slf4j-api and the required Slf4j-bridges (jcl-over-slf4j, log4j-over-slf4j) in the main/common/launch class-path.
- remove everything else that has anything to do with logging (log4j, commons-logging, etc.). The "dependencyManagement with scope provided" trick mentioned in the comments by Pavel Horal can come in handy here.
- for some components you need to programmatically set Slf4j as logger, e.g. for Hibernate 4.3 use `System.setProperty("org.jboss.logging.provider", "slf4j");` before Hibernate is started.
- if Slf4j cannot be set as logger for a component, try setting Log4j. The slf4j-bridge "log4j-over-slf4j" will redirect the logging from Log4j to Slf4j and Slf4j will send it to the logging implementation (Logback). Note that you only need the bridge jar-file "log4j-over-slf4j" and NOT the log4j-jar (the bridge will provide replacements for the Log4j classes) in your main class-path.

You should now have only one jar-file and/or class in your entire assembly for your application for each logging related component mentioned in the first point of the clean-up. Double check that there are no logging related jar-files in any of the web-apps (WEB-INF/lib folders). On a side node: if you use JDBC-drivers, follow the same procedure (these tend to give trouble as well if they are not in the main class-path).

Before you start the clean-up you should verify your basic setup by using Logback with the Jetty embedded [Hello World example](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/advanced-embedding.html).

It takes some effort to get all this logging going but, as you said, it is required for production and it has helped me during development: simply switching on trace/debugging for a third-party component (via a logger-category in logback-test.xml) can provide a lot of insight in what is happening (especially when combined with unit-tests).

Answer (score 0):

I had this proble. Turns out I found an embarrasingly easy sollution (in my case).

Jetty didn't find my slf4j-*.jar(s) unless I added them as dependencies to the plugin configuration itself. I will not include my entire `pom.xml` but merely the plugin conf. Hope this helps.

Cheers

```
...
  <plugin>
<groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>8.1.10.v20130312</version>
<configuration>
  <webAppConfig>
  </webAppConfig>
</configuration>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.fabric3</groupId>
    <artifactId>fabric3-atomikos-library</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.6</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.btm</groupId>
        <artifactId>btm-jetty6-lifecycle</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
      </dependency>
</dependencies>
  </plugin>
...
```

I then checked the project dependency tree using the Maven Dependency Plugin and removed/excluded all unwanted logging frameworks included by dependencies and it worked.